# Formatting Buttons on Dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, button, dreamweaver

I was wondering how you format the color and style of buttons in Dreamweaver. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find your answer in following article:

[Dreamweaver Tips & Tutorials](http://www.entheosweb.com/website_design/dreamweaver_tips.asp)

Here are some useful/related links for you:

- [Stylish Buttons](http://www.webreference.com/programming/css_stylish/)
- [How to make stylish buttons with CSS](http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html)
- [CSS Button Designer](http://www.pagetutor.com/button_designer/index.html)